# Angular HTML binding not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying iterate over an array and create a DOM which is working fine but `pipe` is not working. I followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding) but this is also not working here.

Here is the json

```
[{
  "question":"What is this in QUestiom?",
  "ans":"<strong> this </strong> is only question"

},{
  "question":"What is the output of following code ?",
  "ans":"vgvfvfg"
},{
  "question":"What is the output of following code ?",
  "ans":"fcfcff"
}]
```

HTML

```
  <div *ngFor="let ques of questionseries;let i =index" class="test">
  <div>
    <span [innerHTML]="ques.question | safeHTML"> </span>
  </div>
  <div>{{ques.ans}}</div>
</div>
```

Custom Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHTML',
  pure:false
})
export class SafeHTMLPipe implements PipeTransform {
 constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
   console.log(value , args);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
 }
```

Here is the working [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eltcxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.pipe.ts).My expectation is `this` will be inside `strong` but it is only correctly rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line needs to bind to innerHTML as well :

```
  <div>{{ques.ans}}</div>
```

To be as follows:

```
  <div [innerHTML]="ques.ans | safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: oops you are right. I missed the very basic. I will accept it as answer