# Treating output from a database as HTML code within angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, format

I'm creating a front end application which looks at a database of Hearthstone cards allowing you to sort and search them. However, the Text displayed on the cards (Within the database) has HTML formatting within it such as `<b> </b>`

EG: 
The card "Toxic Arrow" has a text field containing:

`Deal $2 damage to a minion. If it survives, give it <b>Poisonous</b>.`

currently the rendering function looks as follows:

```
 `<tr *ngFor = "let card of cards">
     <td> {{card.text}} </td>
     <td> <img [src] = 'card.img'
         [title] = 'card.name'
         [style.width.px] = ImageWidth> </td>
  </tr> `
```

and currently the output within the table shows this:
`Deal $2 damage to a minion. If it survives, give it <b>Poisonous</b>.`

I'm looking for a way to format this text quickly inside this loop to remove the $ and use the already existing HTML `<b>` tag

I'm not using the older AngularJs, I'm using the most current up to date version of Angular.

Comment: This has been answered many times, you will need to implement a pipe to allow the HTML (make it safe), check it here for instance: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856903/angular-html-binding-not-working)

Comment: Thankyou i couldn't find any thing that made sense to me

Comment: use [innerHTML] to bind data.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the first `<td>` in your code with `<td [innerHTML]="card.text"> </td>`.
This will cause the text to be displayed with HTML formatting as per the tags present in the input string.

Comment: But what if it was a <a> tag? I tried this it kinda works but it is not clickable.

Comment: it should work with proper formatting, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698434/i-want-to-embed-an-anchor-tag-into-innerhtml-using-angular-but-it-doesnt-recog)