# innerHtml is not displaying the <a> tag in Angular

Tags: html, angular, database, innerhtml

I have this data that I need to display from my database and it was a `<a>` tag. I've tried doing  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486957/treating-output-from-a-database-as-html-code-within-angular) But the output was only like this:

> Payment

I want an output like this

> [Payment](https://#)

**EDIT: **
This tag is from database:

`<a routerLink="/main/payment/5728068320760030">Payment</a>`

What I did in the Html part was like this:

```
<div innerHtml="x.Purpose"></div>
```

Still, the output is like this:

Note: I just want to use the `<a>` for my users to go easily to that path

> Payment

Comment: Can you try `<div [innerHTML]="x.Purpose">` (with square brackets and upper-case "HTML"?

Comment: Be aware that if the HTML can be altered by regular users, your site might become vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: @Ivar I did what you said, still nothing happen it is just showing the word Payment

Comment: @Ivar do you have any recommendations then?

Comment: What happens if you just use `<div>{{x.Purpose}}</div>`? Does it then show the HTML as text? Or still just "Payment"?

Comment: If you Google for "Cross Site Scripting" or "XSS, there will be plenty of information on the subject.

Comment: if i use the <div>{{x.Purpose}}</div> it would literally show <a href="payment/123"> stuff

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220617/angular-12-d3-tree-displaying-a-routerlink